# Use asyncio with threads in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, multithreading, bots, python-asyncio, python-telegram-bot

```
concurrency_limit = 3
semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(concurrency_limit)

async def send_pdf(last_update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    async with semaphore:
        chat_id = last_update.effective_chat.id
        msg = last_update.effective_message.text
        html_path = f"{HTML_PATH}/{msg}{chat_id}.html"
        pdf_path = f"{PDF_PATH}/{msg}{chat_id}{msg}.pdf"
        json_path = f"{JSON_PATH}/{msg}{chat_id}{msg}.json"
        
        await context.bot.send_message(
            chat_id=chat_id, text="يتم البحث عن الوظائف قد يستغرق الوقت دقيقتين ..."
        )
        
        # Run the blocking script in a separate thread
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, run_wuzzuf_script, msg)
        
        await context.bot.send_message(
            chat_id=chat_id, text="جاري انشاء ملف الpdf الخاص بك"
        )
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        
        # Generate the HTML page
        page = f"""
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                    <title>Job Details</title>
                    {STYLE}
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1>Jobs For {msg}</h1><div class="container">{return_html_code(data)}</div></body></html>
                """
        
        # Write data to JSON file
        write_dict_to_json(data, json_path)
        
        # Write the HTML page to a file
        with open(html_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            file.write(page)
        
        # Convert HTML to PDF in a separate thread
        await loop.run_in_executor(None, convert_html_to_pdf, html_path, pdf_path)
        
        await context.bot.send_message(
            chat_id=chat_id, text="المسات الاخير انتظر ثواني"
        )
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        
        # Send the PDF document
        with open(pdf_path, "rb") as pdf_file:
            await context.bot.send_document(chat_id=chat_id, document=pdf_file)
        await context.bot.send_message(
            chat_id=chat_id, text="شكرا لاستخدامك هذا البوت"
            )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(BOT_TOKEN).build()

    # Command Handler
    start_command = CommandHandler("start", start_cmd)
    send_handler = MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, send_pdf)

    # Register Command
    application.add_handler(start_command)
    application.add_handler(send_handler)

    application.run_polling()
```

When I run this code and send message from 2 telegram accounts in the same time, start process for one user and when it end start for another but I want to start in the same time for users and don't let any one wait another while end.

Answer (score 0):

The features that PTB provides for such cases are

- the argument [`block`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.basehandler.html#telegram.ext.BaseHandler.params.block) of all handlers
- the setting [`ApplicationBuilder.concurrent_updates`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.applicationbuilder.html#telegram.ext.ApplicationBuilder.concurrent_updates)
- the method [`Application.crate_task`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.application.html#telegram.ext.Application.create_task)

These are also elaborated on [this wiki page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Concurrency). Which of those features you should use and to what extend depends highly on the overall setup of your code and your specific requirements. I will therefore not make a recommendation.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`